# how to fetch the UITableViewCell row value to UIButton action method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

Hi in my application I'm the fetching data from server and displaying in `UITableViewCell` and I have the dynamic `UIButtons` in my  `UITableView` . Now I want to get the `UITableViewCell` data to my `UIButton` action method.

My code to fetch server data.

```
 -(void) retrieveData
 {
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    menuarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    menuarray1=[NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray * respArray = [json objectForKey:@"nonveg_biriyani"];

  for (int i=0; i<respArray.count; i++)
     {

        NSString * pal = [[respArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * tll = [[respArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cost"];
       [menuarray addObject:pal];
       [menuarray1 addObject:tll];
     }

   [self.mytableview reloadData];
 }
```

My `UITableViewCell` code.

```
  -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
      return 1;
 }
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return menuarray.count;
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

     meunuCell *cell =(meunuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {

         cell = [[meunuCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       }

        cell.name.text=[menuarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.ctt.text=[menuarray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(280,20, 40.0, 40.0);
        [button2 setTitle:@"add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod2:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button1.tag=indexPath.row;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];


        }

   return cell;

  }
```

`UIButton` Action method.

```
  -(void)aMethod2:(id)sender
 {
    int tag=[sender tag];
    NSString *item=[self.menuarray objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",item);
    NSString *cost=[self.menuarray1 objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",cost);

 }
```

I have used the above code to fetch the `UITableViewCell` data its not working its showing the first row data only Please tell where I have done wrong in my above code how to fetch the data to my `UIButton` action method I have to stuck here for long time please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Set 

           [button2 setTag:indexPath.row]; 

before adding button as subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allocate the `UIButton` as `cellforRowAtIndexPath` in directly, other wise u get the result of last index on your button action method

```
    UIButton  *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(280,20, 40.0, 40.0);
    [button2 setTitle:@"add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod2:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button2.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
```

your action method as

```
 -(void)aMethod2:(UIButton*)sender
 {

 NSString *item=[self.menuarray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
 NSLog(@"%@",item);
 NSString *cost=[self.menuarray1 objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
 NSLog(@"%@",cost);

 }
```

Comment: if its works , k other wise u need some modification , i change my code

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up button tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
button2.tag = indexPath.row;
```

The default value is 0 so now every time you have 0 as a tag in aMethod2: method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `button2` has no tag, actually you are giving a tag to `button1` but adding your target to `button2`.

> button1.tag=indexPath.row;

Try to change to this:

> button2.tag=indexPath.row;

Answer (score 0):

if you want the every cell acting the same way, you can simply by using the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to progress the action.